# Save vector layer features into separate layers, based on combination of two attribute values: correct QGIS expression

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression, split-by-attribute, select-by-expression

I am doing a lab worksheet and I am having a hard time figuring out what to put in in the expression box.

GENERAL STEP: You need to identify Aspen and Birch (Select by Expression) and export these stands to a separate shapefile, naming it something like
AspenBirch.shp. Then open the AspenBirch attribute table and alternately
select the young, intermediate, or old tree stands, exporting each to create three new shapefiles.

Out of the 506 Vegetation records, 111 are Aspen or Birch. Of these:

- 30 records are Young; less than 18 year, from 2006 through 1988
- 25 records are Intermediate; between 19-34 years, from 1987
  through 1972
- 30 records are Old; 34 years and over, from 1971 to 1888.

Below is the attribute table data that the records are in. I am a beginner QGIS user so I am still learning how to come up with the correct valid expressions.

[image]

UPDATE: I have entered in the adjusted expression in the field calculator like in the answer reply but under my Category all it shows is NULL values. I may have made a small mistake but I can't tell since the expression doesn't show anything invalid.[image]

Comment: Can you please share what statements you have tried?  It appears the ORIGIN field is not a numerical data type, but instead a string data type.

Answer (score 4):

To resume your question: you need 6 new vector files (2*3): for each `Cover_type` (Aspen and Birch) one for each of three age categories.

Instead of doing it one by one, I advice to do it at once by categorizing your features and then split the layer (based on these categories) in 6 layers containing subsets of the initial data. As your `ORIGIN` field contains years in string (text) format, you have to convert them to integers using [`to_int()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#to-int):

1. Categorize your values: create a new field called `category` using field calculator with this expression based on [`case ... when`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#case) condition and concatenate `ORIGIN` and `Cover_Type` using [pipes operator `||`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-operators-concat) :

   ```
    case
        when to_int(ORIGIN) >= 1988 then 'young'
        when to_int(ORIGIN) <= 1987 and to_int(ORIGIN) >=1972 then 'intermediate'
        when  to_int(ORIGIN) < 1972 then 'Old'
    end || '_'  || 
    case 
        when Cover_Type ='Birch' then 'Birch'
        when Cover_Type = 'Aspen' then 'Aspen'
    end
   ```
2. Run Menu <kbd>Processing</kbd> > <kbd>Toolbox</kbd> > <kbd>Split vector layer</kbd> and use the category field created as input for `Unique ID field`.

You're done.

*By the way: Is there a reason you want to save as shapefile? Geopackage would be a good alternative.*

*Step 1:*
[image]

*Step 2:*
[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you appreciated. Apologies for the inconsistencies, my lab instructions tell me that I need to identify the Aspen & Birch stands under the 3 conditions and filter them regarding by the years and to make them into 3 new shapefiles.

Comment: I have an issue after I enter in the expression in the field calculator and under Category it shows as NULL for every value so I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong. I changed the original data to integer from text string and under Category it still shows NULL values.

Comment: You must adapt the expression to the field values you have. If it doesn't work, post a screenshot showing the same as my first screenshot

Comment: Screenshot posted. I'm not sure what I did that's causing it to show NULL values

Comment: Can you share your data, at least sample data, for testing?

Comment: Are you sure you have any entries in your data with the value `Paper Birch-B`? I can't see any on your first screenshot. Also be sure to introduce the values exactly as they are in your data - in the expression you have `Aspen-A`, but on your screenshot I think its `Aspen - A` with spaces. Your expression should match exactly. There are ways to match even without being 100% the same, but we don't want to complicate things. Please have a look at your data an be precise!

Comment: Yes, you are right I wasn't adding the space between. It worked. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. As a new user, please be adviced that the policy of this site is to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer if it solved the problem and/or upvote it if you found it helpful: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235